# Properly Displaying Sorted SQL Rows

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to sort my SQL database alphabetically by location. I executed the command: `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY location` on the phpMyAdmin website, and the users are now indeed ordered alphabetically by location on the online database. However they still don't display in alphabetical order on our website. Here is the code where I output the relevant SQL data:

```
<div>
  <table id="checkintable">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>                  
  <? $result = mysql_query("SELECT fullname, location, comment FROM users"); ?>
  <? while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
    <tr class="tables">
        <td><?= $row["fullname"]?></td>
        <td><?= $row["location"]?></td>
        <td><?= $row["comment"]?></td>
    </tr>
    <br>
  <? endwhile ?>
  </table>
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong in this code? I want to display the table in the same order that the online database is ordered in, but it isn't working.

Comment: I don't understand why you're missing "order by location".  You even mention that you used it from the mysql command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your:

```
mysql_query("SELECT fullname, location, comment FROM users")
```

to:

```
mysql_query("SELECT fullname, location, comment FROM users ORDER BY location")
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `ORDER BY location` in your query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT fullname, location, comment FROM users ORDER BY location");
```